# PHP Datetime not working properly

Tags: php, datetime

I am retrieving the datetime data from mysql the retrieved data from a single row is.

```
2011-04-11 19:31:30
```

I wanted to reformat the datetime in `d-m-Y H:i:s` for that I am using `date_format()` the below code works just fine.

```
$date = new DateTime($users['registerDate']);
echo $date->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

However, I don't want to go object oriented way just for reformatting because I will be using the code within the foreach loop and that means I would have to initialize the DateTime class again and again.

I tried doing this the Procedural way using the following code.

```
$date = $users['registerDate'];
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

the above code does not work for me and gives back the following error.

> Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kokaris/administrator/resources/library/models/users/users.php on line 21

What could be possibly wrong?

The given solution works perfectly fine for the procedural way.

```
echo date('m-d-Y',strtotime($users['registerDate']));
```

However I would like to know which will be the best feasible solution the above procedural way or the OOP way.

```
 $date = new DateTime($users['registerDate']);
 echo $date->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

Considering I will be using the code within a foreach loop and it may loop for over a hundred times.

Comment: The first parameter to `date_format()` must be an instance of `DateTime`. You're passing it a string

Comment: In PHP, instantiating an object is not a very expensive operation, at least not compared to other things you do all the time. Choosing procedural code over object-oriented purely out of performance considerations is silly in languages like PHP.

Comment: @tdammers are you sure it is ok to use OOP way for the given condition ill be uisng it within the loop? for example if i have to retrieve 100 records considering it will initialize the class 100 times, for condition like this is it not good to use just procedural function() ?

Comment: It would probably be fine, but in the given situation, just using `date()` is a much better solution - not for performance reasons though, but because it is easier to read. Also, 100 iterations is nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need "date_format()":

```
echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime('2011-04-11 19:31:30'));

//results: 11-04-2011 19:31:30
```

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to use a function/object that is part of the DateTime class without creating a reference to the DateTime class.

For procedural formatting take a look at [date()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeking for is this:

```
date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime('2011-04-11 19:31:30'));
```

Have a look at the php-manual. However, using the methods you yourself proposed is pretty fine, since the DateTime-object maps to some functions written in C.

Also PHP Datetime *is* working properly, since date_format is just an alias of Date::format, which *does* exactly require what you don’t want to pass in (a DateTime-object).

Honestly, we’re talking about PHP...